# JQ: Show the contents/value of a single-element array

Tags: json, jq

My JSON file:

```
{
    "MetricAlarms": [
        {
            "EvaluationPeriods": 2,
            "AlarmActions": [
                "this is causing me trouble"
            ],
            "Threshold": 0.0,
            "Dimensions": [
                {
                    "Name": "DBInstanceIdentifier",
                    "Value": "db-master02"
                }
            ],
            "MetricName": "ReplicaLag"
        }
    ]
}
```

My current command to flatten the JSON file (jq 1.3, cannot upgrade right now):

```
cat $JSON_FILE |
   jq -r '.MetricAlarms[] |
          { MetricName,
            Threshold,
            EvaluationPeriods,
            AlarmActions
          } +
          ( .Dimensions[] | { DimName: .Name, DimValue: .Value } )
   '
```

produces:

```
{
  "DimName": "DBInstanceIdentifier",
  "DimValue": "db-master02",
  "AlarmActions": [
    "this is causing me trouble"
  ],
  "EvaluationPeriods": 2,
  "Threshold": 0,
  "MetricName": "ReplicaLag"
}
```

What I really want:

```
{
  "DimName": "DBInstanceIdentifier",
  "DimValue": "db-master02",
  "AlarmActions": "this is causing me trouble",
  "EvaluationPeriods": 2,
  "Threshold": 0,
  "MetricName": "ReplicaLag"
}
```

I want to show the value for "AlarmActions" without an array.

This seems like a simple problem, but the answer eludes me.  I have tried treating "AlarmActions" in a manner similar to the way I treat "Dimensions".  I have tried every variation of [], [0], periods, pipes, and function calls I can think of, but to no avail.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
cat $JSON_FILE |
jq -r '.MetricAlarms[] |
      { MetricName,
        Threshold,
        EvaluationPeriods,
        "AlarmActions" : .AlarmActions[0]
      } +
      ( .Dimensions[] | { DimName: .Name, DimValue: .Value } )
'
```

i.e. don't use  shortcut syntax for the `AlarmActions` element.

Comment: Thank you Hans.  That is perfect.